# How to get the name of a product's sale

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am still new to craft commerce and I have 5 sales, some are flat and others are percent. When i loop through my products, I am trying to get the type of the sale for the current product. How do i get that?

Comment: Is this Commerce 1 or Commerce 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for sale in variant.sales %}
  {{sale.name}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```